# addEventListener() just executes once

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The problem is that when I click the element with the class `circulo` it runs the function, but when I click on it again it does not do anything at all.

This is the code of the function.

```js
function showTexto(texto) {
    var status = 1;
    document.querySelector('.circulo').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("hola")
        if (status == 1) {
            block = document.querySelector('.quedadas-content-body-p');
            tostyle = block.style;
            tostyle.minHeight = "100%";
            tostyle.background = "#222"
            block.innerHTML += `
                            <p class = "text-extra">${texto}</p>`;
            tostyle.display = "block";
            document.querySelector('.quedadas-content-body-p svg').style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
            document.querySelector('.quedadas-content-body-p p').style.margin = "0 10px";

            status = 0;
        } else {
            console.log("status = 0");
            block = document.querySelector('.quedadas-content-body-p');
            block.removeAttribute("style");
            document.querySelector('.text-extra').remove();
            document.querySelector('.quedadas-content-body-p svg').removeAttribute("style");

            status = 1;
        }
        console.log(status);
    });
    console.log("statusasdf");
}
```

I'm executing this function in my ajax implementation.

```js
axios("json/").then(res=>{
    responsiveHtml(res.data);
    window.addEventListener('resize', _=> responsiveHtml(res.data));
    showTexto( res.data.quedadas[3].texto);
})
```

Comment: You're replacing all the elements in `block` with new elements when setting `innerHTML`. Use a proper [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) methods instead. Also, `window.resize` fires tens of times per second, you're adding a new click listener every time.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, you have help me to improve my skills and with the changes applied the problem has been dissolved.